# Set dynamic variabe in the Datapower context

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

My requirement is to set some dynamic variables in a for loop to the datapower context something like :

```
<dp:set-variable name="'var://context/txn-info/appErrorInd[$i+1]'"
                value="'yes'" />
```

The variable $i will keep on changing. The above code isn't working. Can somebody give me a solution?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
<dp:set-variable name="'var:{//context/txn-info/appErrorInd[$i+1]}'"
                 value="'yes'" />
```

The above is a mechanical correction of the provided code. Most likely it contains another, more subtle error. To correct this error, too, use:

```
<dp:set-variable name="'var:{(//context/txn-info/appErrorInd)[$i+1]}'"
                 value="'yes'" />
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**.
2. The `[]` operator has a higher precedence than the `//` pseudo-operator. To override this one needs to use explicitly brackets.

Comment: Sorry for pinching in for this question now. Did not understand the above. Cant we use <dp:set-variable name="'{(var://context/txn-info/appErrorInd)[$i+1]}'"
                 value="'yes'" />. Why the 'var:' part, kept oustside the curly braces?

Comment: @user1004770: The string `"var:"` is constant -- not dynamically calculated. It is meaningful to use AVT (the {} brackets) for specifying dynamically-calculated values.